# Are Facebook admin posts and announcements on a Group visible to a user that has blocked the admin but still follows the Group?

Tags: facebook-groups

I am Facebook admin of a private Sales & Wants Group. I created the Group to sell books from my collection to members with similar niche interests and as well as private members buying and selling books there are several large book dealers who sell on the Group as well. Sometimes people who buy from me friend me to make messaging easier, so I would say I am friends with maybe 2/3 of group members but not all.

Recently a member of the Group who friended me took exception to a comment I posted outside the Group and decided not just to unfriend me but to block me on Facebook. But they remained a member of the Group. I suspect because they are a book collector they find the Group a useful source of bargains. Of course I could remove them but being the bigger person I'm not going to as

1. Will be accused of being "intolerant of their views" if I remove them (I'm not intolerant, we just differ politically) and
2. I suspect the problem may solve itself in time.

A lot of the posts on the Group are limited time offers so it makes sense to follow the Group. Obviously this member isn't going to be buying off me anymore but they'll want to see the offers of other members.

Here's my question. I regularly post sales offers and make Admin announcements 2-3 times a week. We also have a loyalty scheme so I am regularly posting announcements about that. If this person continues to remain a member of the Group and follow the Group, won't they continue to see my Admin sales and loyalty announcements on their feed as part of the follow?

I ask because presumably that leaves them with the option of either unfollowing the Group (and missing out on offers from other sellers) or just getting sick of seeing the announcements and leaving the Group without me having to remove them as a member (which I am loathe to do).

So...will the problem solve itself?